# Plot subtitle is lost when plot is diplayed with ggplotly()

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

I create the ggplot below with title and subitle but when I diplay it using `ggplotly()` the subtitle is lost.

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x = factor(dose), y = len)) + 
  geom_boxplot()
library(plotly)
p <- p + labs(title = "Effect of Vitamin C on Tooth Growth",
              subtitle = "Plot of length by dose",
              caption = "Data source: ToothGrowth")
ggplotly(p)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x = factor(dose), y = len)) + 
  geom_boxplot()
library(plotly)
p <- p + labs(title = "Effect of Vitamin C on Tooth Growth",
              subtitle = "Plot of length by dose",
              caption = "Data source: ToothGrowth")
ggplotly(p)%>% 
  layout(title = list(text = paste0('Effect of Vitamin C on Tooth Growth"',
                                    '<br>',
                                    '<sup>',
                                    'Plot of length by dose','</sup>')))
```

This works let me know if it fixes your issue